# Easiest way for deploying Python/Django app on a Windows Machine?

Tags: python, django, deployment

I need to deploy a Django project on a remote Windows machine, but due to constraints in the project I can't access the machine - I have to give it to another person who will be charged for deploying it.

The question is, what would be the easiest way to deploy my application on that machine, I'm looking for something like an install package or script?

Comment: FTP? The server (Apache? IIS?) would still need to be set up properly once, though...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion bitnami - djangostack will solve your problem.
It's free and easy to set up

http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack/